# Can you set height to a percent of an auto value of a parent?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
       Heading.
    </div>
    Content.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{ height: auto}
.header{ height: 10%}
```

The `.container` is set to `height: auto` because of the nature of the content, so it needs to be elastic. Therefore, when you set `.header{ height: 10%}` it doesn't properly behave (it isn't 10% of the `.container` height.

Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: This doesn't work because changing the size of the container will change the height of the header, which in turn will change the height of the container, etc. You could use Javascript, or rethink your website design - if the content is huge, the header will become huge as well, or if the content is small, the header will barely be visible.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that - cheers.